# Stop QGIS opening in a new workspace in Ubuntu

Tags: qgis

Very basic issue I imagine other Ubuntu users will have encountered: every time you open QGIS, it does so in a new workspace - note the arrow in the sidebar is empty not full, just after opening QGIS. I can see how this could be useful, if you want full screen editing and stuff, but it can also be really annoying!

Anyone else had this issues?

Sure there's a very simple solution, I've just not found it yet!

[image: qgis-load]

Comment: I've never experienced this with QGIS on ubuntu, but have experienced it with other applications... Perhaps something for askubuntu.com?

Comment: This is not an issue on Ubuntu 12.04, which version are you using? In any case, this is an Ubuntu related issue, not exactly a QGis problem.

Comment: OK - it's 12.04. Any ideas how to move this to askubuntu then? Thanks